# classlist.toggle() does not work as expected on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

I have a function to add an open class to a drop down menu so it stays open on mobile browsers
the function worked fine also on safari, but now I saw it doesn't work on safari like before
the problem: it opens up the drop down menu but it doesn't close anymore only if you reload the site (or switch to another one)

tested I have nothing as I have no clue what even could go wrong with that code.
in chrome, firefox, edge also in chrome on android it's working fine

the function is the following (very simple)

```
function togglenav(tagid) {
    document.getElementById(tagid).classList.toggle('navopen');
}
```

any idea what could go wrong only on safari?

edit: correctet the sentence that should tell on what browsers it's working (forgott the part that stated this)

Comment: ClassList is not supported by safari < 5.1, on some older iPhones the property might not be present at all. Could you check your safari version?

Comment: i don't have a iphone myself, a friend tested it for me on his phone it worked he told me that he means it's an older version longer not updated. some days ago someone told me it's not working for him and another friend tested it again (he meant it's not older than one month his safari version) - if my other friend has time again to test (with the older safari version) he will test it again

Comment: oh i forgot, the friend that tested it for me with the older safari version, the test where it worked was like a year ago the code didn't changed since then (and was never tested again from anyone with an iphone)

Comment: classList problems are present on new iPhone X as well. The toggle doesn't take any effect until another event follows.. strange.. I was hoping to get a solution from here.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas sadly i never found one for this, but this was just the fix for mobiles (iphone specifically) where the css drop down didn't work. but i found the solution for fixing the css drop down on iphone so it atleast opens even tho it can't be closed. for anybody interested: for the dropdown to work with :hover it hast to be an element where the browser knows it has an action, like the a tag, adding a onclick=""; works too. i did both, made it an a tag with onclick to prevent the # set as heref appearing in the link itself.

Answer (score 0):

### Reload without content blockers?

Not sure if this is the same case as you're experiencing, but I had [almost identical JavaScript](https://github.com/CTEC3905/04-lab/tree/js-menu) that worked in mobile Safari on my wife’s iPhone X, but not on my iPhone 6. Turns out the model was irrelevant. I had the [Better](https://better.fyi/) ad/tracking blocker running on my iPhone which stopped the script from loading.

If this is the case, tap/hold the URL and “reload without content blockers”. Worked for me, but worth bearing in mind that mobile Safari on my wife’s phone loaded it without a hitch.